# Issue in the package "nomencl"

Tags: miktex, nomenclature

When I issue the command

```
makeindex thesis22May.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o thesis22May.nls
```

in Dos prompt, it creates `thesis22May.nls` file which I use during compilation of the main `thesis22May.tex` to get the nomenclature printed.

But when add in my Tex code

```
\nomenclature{$|\mathbb{L}|$}{Cardinality of the set $\mathbb{L}$}
```

it rejects this entry from the `.nls` file and in the log file it says "

```
Unknown specifier lethead_prefix.
```

Then I tried removing `|`, then it works fine.

Anybody knows this issue in the package `nomencl` and any solutions?

Comment: You could also use `$\lvert\mathbb{L}\rvert$` in your code. This requires loading the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Hi cmhuges, Understood your idea.  It works.  Great and thanks a ton.

Answer (score 5):

The log file of Makeindex says:

```
!! Input index error (file = test.nlo, line = 1):
   -- Extra `|' at position 14 of first argument.
```

The other three messages `Unknown specifier lethead_...` are warnings
and can be ignored here.

The reason for the error is that `|` is used as `encap` character. The text after the symbol is used as command to format the page number. Makeindex only supports *one* encap command. Therefore you have to quote the symbol with the quote character `"` to get rid of the special meaning of `|` as encap symbol:

```
\nomenclature{$"|\mathbb{L}"|$}{Cardinality of the set $\mathbb{L}$}
```

Comment: Thanks Heiko Oberdiek.  This also works.  Also got why Makeindex does not support | symbol directly.